# Get PDF form field description with VBScript

Tags: pdf, vbscript

I'm pretty new to VB, but I've got a script working which involves taking a PDF with fillable fields, and populating a column in an xlsx with all of the field names.

I would like to take this a step further, and pull the field descriptions as well, into another column. By that, I mean the description which comes up when mousing over a particular field in the form. Getting the name of the field is easy enough, but I've done some digging and am not sure if it's possible to pull the description as easily.

I've experimented with functions similar to "object.getNthFieldName(x)," but no such luck.

Not entirely sure if this is possible, but looking for any insight. Thanks!

Comment: Do you get the field names with getNthFieldName(x) ? With that, you could create a field object, from which you then can extract the various properties (assuming that you get the Acrobat JavaScript engine running).

Comment: @MaxWyss- Thanks for the quick response. I was, indeed, pulling field names as "fname," via `fname=jso.getNthFieldName(i)`. I created a field object in the next line, via `Set currField=jso.getField(fname)`. I was also able to find that the "description" property I was looking for is officially called `userName`, after finding this detailed [JavaScript for Acrobat API Reference](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/js_api_reference.pdf). So with that, I simply set `fdescription=currField.userName`. Thanks for sending me on the right track!

Comment: You're welcome; I presume that jso stands for JavaScript Object, and for using it, you will definitely need the Acrobat JavaScript documentation (as you found correctly).